# Profile URL gets mangled on Area 51 when cycling through someone's example questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

To reproduce: go to a profile (for example, http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/9549/lesspop-morefizz). Scroll down to example questions and either change pages or sort tabs.

The URL in the address bar of my browser then ends up looking like this:

> `http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/9549/lesspop-morefizz#ppage_1-ccpage_1-fcpage_1-fppage_1-epage_1-psort_Model.Sort.ToString().ToLower()-ccsort_Model.Sort.ToString().ToLower()-fcsort_Model.Sort.ToString().ToLower()-fpsort_Model.Sort.ToString().ToLower()-esort_votes`

The sort isn't broken and everything appears to work, the URL itself is obviously not right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an age-old bug introduced during our switch to [Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx). It's fixed now.